# What do setDither,setFilterBitmap and setAntiAlias do in a Canvas?

Tags: android, bitmap, android-canvas

Usually samples that I see,use this methods when try to draw bitmaps on canvas.[For example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4294195/1043882):

```
paint.setAntiAlias(true);
paint.setFilterBitmap(true);
paint.setDither(true);
```

But I do not know what those three methods do?When I have to use them?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

From the [doc](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Paint.html)

[Paint.setAntiAlias](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Paint.html#setAntiAlias%28boolean%29)

> Helper for setFlags(), setting or clearing the ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG bit
>   AntiAliasing smooths out the edges of what is being drawn, but is has
>   no impact on the interior of the shape. See setDither() and
>   setFilterBitmap() to affect how colors are treated.

[Paint.setFilterBitmap](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Paint.html#setFilterBitmap%28boolean%29)

> Helper for setFlags(), setting or clearing the FILTER_BITMAP_FLAG bit.
>   Filtering affects the sampling of bitmaps when they are transformed.
>   Filtering does not affect how the colors in the bitmap are converted
>   into device pixels. That is dependent on dithering and xfermodes.

[Paint.setDither](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Paint.html#setDither%28boolean%29)

> Helper for setFlags(), setting or clearing the DITHER_FLAG bit
>   Dithering affects how colors that are higher precision than the device
>   are down-sampled. No dithering is generally faster, but higher
>   precision colors are just truncated down (e.g. 8888 -> 565). Dithering
>   tries to distribute the error inherent in this process, to reduce the
>   visual artifacts.

Comment: An example of these three would be appreciated, or at least a friendlier explanation. I couldn't understand the literal docs.

Answer (score 2):

I want to explain that how anti-alias produces a smooth edge, it works by blending the foreground and background colors to create a smoother edge. like if background color is transparent and the foreground color is blue, anti aliasing will make the pixels on the edge go from blue to transparent **gradually**. This makes the edge look smooth to the eye.