# Android Draw Bitmap to Canvas

Tags: android, android-canvas

I'm trying to draw a `Bitmap` to a `Canvas` in a custom `SurfaceView`, but it doesn't show up anywhere.

In the `SurfaceView`, I'm using:

```
//in the constructor
Bitmap leftUp = BitmapFactory.decodeResources(R.drawable.leftup);
leftCurrent = leftUp; //it's a button - leftUp and leftDown

//in my drawing method
canvas.drawBitmap(leftCurrent, controlsWidth, controlsHeight, new Paint());
```

It runs OK, no errors, but nothing shows up.  Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: does your surfaceview have a width and height ? , did you check that controlsWidth and controlsHeight are not 0 ?

Comment: Do you want to draw that on top of another image or on a blank view?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with you paint object that you pass to the drawBitmap method. It must be configured properly. Take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4294102/draw-smoothly-scaled-bitmaps-on-canvas)
answer.

Comment: This link might provide an answer to the question, but it's better if you give some more context to the link. If the link dies, this answer will be useless.